# Releasing a UIViewController as a property

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having an interesting memory management problem with an iOS app.

1. I have a property which when release using `[self.propertyName release];` will cause the property to be released twice and cause a bad memory access exception on an iPad 1/iOS 4 device (in the dealloc of the property).
2. When the this code is changed to `[_propertyName release];` (accessing the local variable instead of the property), this will cause a leak on an iPad 3/iOS 5.

**Of course**, I can stop this from happening by checking the OS version, but I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

Some more details:

The property is a subclass of `UIViewController`, as is the object who owns the property. I am adding the property's `UIView` as a subview. I have heard this is not good practice, but we are doing it elsewhere without the memory problems.

The test cases are:

- iPad 1, iOS 4.2 - Needs to release using the ivar `[_propertyName release]`
- iPad 2, iOS 5.0 - Needs to release using the property `[self.propertyName release]`
- iPad 3, iOS 5.1 - Needs to release using the property `[self.propertyName release]`

Comment: We need code to go on.  Show the declaration of this var, and where you are releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another viewController's view as a subview is bound to cause strange issues, when you release the other viewController it's view will still be retained by your main view but it's viewController will have disappeared.

That said `self.propertyName = nil` is the best way to release properties, just make sure you have removed the subview from your main view first.